# Beginners resources for SEO

Tags: seo

I'm totally new to the business of SEO - what are good resources to get started?

When I try to Google such a question I end up quickly at black-hat and paid sites; I'm looking for the white-hat variety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple resources that helped me get started:

- [Google's guide on creating Google-friendly Sites](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40349).
- Automate My Small Business podcast episode: [SEO: Getting Your Website on Page 1 of Google and Bing](http://automatemysmallbusiness.com/seo-getting-your-website-on-page-1-of-google-and-bing-part-1/).

Answer (score 3):

I think one of these days I will write a guide and post it here, but until then you will have to do with the following resources. When I started out I knew there was not much to read until I would have gotten bored and left the whole thing. It is very important to know what you need the SEO for and if you want SEO or also SEM (Search Engine Marketing). If you plan on using only SEO, then read Google's guide on creating Google-friendly Sites is a good resource to start with.

On the other hand, if you want to make money online then you will need much more than some basic knowledge on SEO. Start to look at:

1. SEO Moz Guide - Good reading on SEO
   http://www.seomoz.org/beginners-guide-to-seo
2. http://www.makemoneyonlinewithseo.com/

Daniel.

Answer (score 3):

SEO is big think to learn and here i attached a link, which provide you whole information regarding SEO you should check it : http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/what-is-seo-a-guide-for-beginners/

Answer (score 2):

I keep a repository SEO links here: http://www.qnq.com.au/resources/online-seo-link-repository/

Here's the intro set to get you started:

In the beginning...

- http://www.searchenginehistory.com/

SEO 101

- http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf
- https://docs.google.com/Present?docid=dc3qhbxg_1217d9mwjwg3
- http://help.live.com/
- http://www.bruceclay.com/web_rank.htm
- http://www.websitepublisher.net/seo-guide/
- http://www.highrankings.com/tentips
- http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/seo/
- http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2007/10/how-to-create-1.html
- http://www.webconfs.com/15-minute-seo.php
- http://www.seomoz.org/blog/the-web-developers-seo-cheat-sheet
- http://www.conversationmarketing.com/2010/07/on-page-seo-cheatsheet.htm
- http://www.seo-theory.com/wordpress/2008/09/22/nine-lessons-in-search-engine-optimization/
- http://searchengineland.com/25-super-common-seo-mistakes-51888
- http://www.seobook.com/archives/001792.shtml
- http://www.seobook.com/seo-strategy
- http://www.bing.com/community/blogs/webmaster/archive/2009/06/26/site-architecture-and-seo-file-page-issues-sem-101.aspx
- http://www.searchenginejournal.com/bing-rankings-cheat-sheet/29847/
- http://blog.vkistudios.com/index.cfm/2009/9/2/Server-Status-Codes-and-SEO
- http://www.omniture.com/offer/656/1097 (PDF)
- http://sixrevisions.com/content-strategy/user-friendly-seo/
- http://outspokenmedia.com/seo/10-things-everyone-should-know-about-seo-in-2011/
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecI_hCBGEIM – great 1hr long presentation from Google